# Expressão regular para telefones?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

Eu criei uma directive para formatar telefones com ou sem o digito 9. Agora preciso de uma expressão regular para validar se o formato do número está correto no `ng-pattern`. Criei uma expressão regular mas ainda não estou conseguindo ter resultados se o número é válido ou não.

Como fazer isso ?

**expressao regular**

```
^\(?\d{2}\)?[\s-]?[\s9]?\d{4}-?\d{4}$
```

**html**

```
<input type="text" 
       placeholder="Telefone"
       name="telemp" 
       ng-model="Empresa.telefone" 
       ui-telefone
       ng-required="true"
       ng-pattern="^\(?\d{2}\)?[\s-]?[\s9]?\d{4}-?\d{4}$">
```

**directive**

```
var app = angular.module('starter');

app.directive('uiTelefone', function(){

    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl){
            var _formatTelefone = function(telefone){

                //(99)9999-9999 - 13dig
                //(99)99999-9999 - 14dig
                telefone = telefone.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, "");                
                if(telefone.length > 0){
                    telefone = telefone.substring(-1,0) + "(" + telefone.substring(0);
                }
                if(telefone.length > 3){
                    telefone = telefone.substring(0,3) + ")" + telefone.substring(3);
                }
                if(telefone.length == 12){
                    telefone = telefone.substring(0,8) + "-" + telefone.substring(8);
                }else if(telefone.length >= 13){
                    telefone = telefone.substring(0,9) + "-" + telefone.substring(9,13);
                }

                return telefone;
            }

            element.bind('keyup', function(){
                ctrl.$setViewValue(_formatTelefone(ctrl.$viewValue));
                ctrl.$render();
            });

        }
    };

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui fazer, eh bem mais simples que eu imaginava.

fiz assim.

```
ng-pattern="/^\([1-9]{2}\)[0-9]{4,5}-[0-9]{4}$/"
```

esse [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9r48XuOB4DA) me ajudou muito.

Answer (score 3):

Eu criei uma expressão regular que identifica se uma string é um telefone, levando em conta os seguintes casos:

> - telefones 0800
> - números de operadoras e serviços como 10315 e 190
> - telefones representados com ou sem parênteses
> - aceita operadora representada como 0xx11
> - telefones com ou sem os separadores [ .-]
> - ignora telefones começados com 0 se não tiver DDD (ex: 0999-9999 não é aceito, mas 0xx11 9123-1234 é)

Ficou um pouco grande e difícil de ler humanamente, mas atende meus projetos:

```
/^1\d\d(\d\d)?$|^0800 ?\d{3} ?\d{4}$|^(\(0?([1-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z])?[1-9]\d\) ?|0?([1-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z])?[1-9]\d[ .-]?)?(9|9[ .-])?[2-9]\d{3}[ .-]?\d{4}$/gm
```

Você pode ver a expressão em uso [neste link](http://regexr.com/3dkvr).

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, dê uma olhada nesta:

```
^(\(11\) [9][0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4})|(\(1[2-9]\) [5-9][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})|(\([2-9][1-9]\) [5-9][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})$
```

Comment: opa, ainda nao funcionou !

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, 
É praticamente o que vc colocou ae em cima, entretanto, no angular, vc tem que iniciar e finalizar com a /.
seria:

```
ng-pattern="/^\(\d{2}\)\d{4,5}-\d{4}$/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa essa com validação do 9 e espaço depois do ddd

```
ng-pattern="^\([1-9]{2}\) [9]{1}[0-9]{4,5}-[0-9]{4}$"
```

Answer (score 0):

Pessoal  eu estou utilizando o angular 8. 
Todo os exemplos não funcionaram para mim. Depois de tanto pesquisar descobri que eu tinha que colocar `\\` antes das strings.
Eu estou utilizando o regex deste site aqui: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/07656880-7c55-4a18-b208-8f4d2c3d69b1/regex-para-numero-de-telefone-comum-ou-celular-com-esse-formato-11-12341234-ou-11-123451234?forum=aspnetpt

No exemplo do site esta assim:

`^(\([0-9]{2}\))\s([9]{1})?([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{4})$`

ai coloquei `\\` e funfou:

`^(\\([0-9]{2}\\))\\s([9]{1})?([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{4})$`

Answer (score -1):

Se você estiver usando o mesmo campo para celular e telefone fixo, basta mudar para: `^[1-9]{2}[0-9]{4,5}[0-9]{4}$`

Comment: É exatamente a expressão das outras respostas, não é? Não entendi a diferença.

Comment: Não, essa modificação que eu fiz te permite usar o campo para qualquer número de telefone (fixo/celular). A anterior permite apenas celular.